# Como alterar cor de fundo do elemento caso exista um determinado elemento filho?

Tags: sass

Tenho a tag body e a cor de fundo será alterada caso exista uma div.login como filha.

```
...
<body>
  <div class="container"><div class="login"></div></div>
<body>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Não existem parent selectors no CSS.

Existem várias maneiras de dinamicamente selecionar o pai de um elemento, mas todas elas envolvem um pouco de JavaScript como, por exemplo, o método parent() do jQuery.

Usando SASS, você pode fazer algo usando o operador ampersand:

Tente usar:

```
div.container {
    body & {
      background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Estou começando agora, não sei se é a melhor maneira de ser fazer. Teste e veja se funciona. Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: com sass eu, realmente, não consegui, fiz o processo com javascript mesmo. vlw